# How to recover the typescript 'this' scope from a d3 function?

Tags: d3.js, scope, typescript

D3 overwrites the 'this' variable, allowing you to see the current selection while in different methods.

I also need 'this' to access class member properties in typescript. I'm currently unsure of how I can retain both whenever I need them.

```
tweenArc(datum: any, index: number, attr: string) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.classVariable);
...
}
```

The first `console.log` will write out the d3 selection, which in this case is an svg element.

If I'm trying to access member properties from the class the function is defined in however, I cannot. That `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Do I need to use the class prototype to pull it out?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have come up with is to change the way I am defining my callback. Instead of putting the callback as a function in the typescript class, I am creating it inline with a lambda, so I have access to my selection which is defined in the wrapping class, plus access to the `this` variable of the typescript class.

If there's a better way I would like to know, since this forces a specific architecture.

```
selection.transition()
            .duration(this.duration)
            .attrTween("d", (datum: any, index: number, attr: string) => {
                let previousEndAngle = parseFloat(selection.attr("endAngle"));
                let endAngle = this.d3Utility.arcPercentage(value, maxValue, startAngle, isClockwise, this.arcLength);
                let interpolator = d3.interpolate(previousEndAngle, endAngle);

                return (t: number): any => {
                    selection.attr("endAngle", interpolator(t));

                    return this.drawArc(startAngle, interpolator(t), radii[0], radii[1])(null);
                }
            });
```